# TextReader Read and ReadToEnd hangs without throwing exception

Tags: c#, ifilter

Is there a way to know that a call to TextReader.Read or TextReader.ReadToEnd call will hang without throwing exeption before I do the call?

```
try
{
 using (var filterReader = new EPocalipse.IFilter.FilterReader(tempFileName))
 {
  mediaContent = filterReader.ReadToEnd();
 }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 Log.Error("DealerPortalIndex Error on file: " + tempFileName, e, this);
 mediaContent = string.Empty;
}
```

filterReader.ReadToEnd() hangs and never throws exception on a certain .xls file (maybe more file)

I have also tried using a filterReader.Read(char{}, int, int) to read block and get the same problem.

Comment: how big are the files that you are trying to read?

Comment: This file is only 179kb and it opens fine in excel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(You say textreader in your code, but the example is using EPocalips IFilter module.)

I think it's a bug in EPocalipse IFilter. I don't know how updated their code is, but I recall something to the same effect some years ago when I was working with IFilters and used the EPocalipse code.

You should run it in the debugger and break the code to see where in the EPocalipse library it's hanging. Most likely it's stuck in a loop.

[Edit]
I found my old updated code and put it up on skydrive ([Epocalipse.IFilter.zip](http://cid-9ecc38025e460fc4.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/EPocalipse.IFilter.zip)). See if it solves your problems. It has detection for infinite IFilter parse loops, and excel files with locked cells.

Comment: I have downloaded the code, built, and added dll to replace mine.  Now it is hanging the workerprocess on the very first pdf it hits.  I am not asking for support for the code example.  I appreciate your help.  Just FYI.

Comment: It's been some time since I used this code so it might fail :) Which PDF IFilter do you use, and any way I can get a copy of the file to test? And did you test the code on your problematic excel file?

Comment: I ended up using a blend of the code you posted and the code I already had.  I mostly just used the extra checks for filter return codes and infinate loops and throwing exceptions.  Thanks again for your help.  I am now indexing 5000+ documents of assorted types successfully.

Comment: thanks for your help Mikael... we struggled with this for hours yesterday. (I work with mbalkema)